# My Lenovo Ideapad S340 crashes randomly with Ubuntu 18.04 & Cinnamon

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, crash, cinnamon, ideapad

As the title says, my Lenovo Ideapad S340 (Intel Core i7, "10th Generation") crashes randomly using Ubuntu 18.04 and there is nothing I can do when this happens. So, the only option I got is to reset my laptop.

I have attached two photos of my screen when the system crashes:

- [Lenovo crashed - Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K48P3.jpg)
- [Lenovo crashed - Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXxjB.jpg)

If you take a look at them, you will see that the entire GUI crashes with a freaky-flickering-mosaic style (this could suggest that the video driver could be failing somehow). The cursor disappears, I am not able to use the keyboard or the mouse.
Also, the sound cuts off with a *plop* noise. So, if I am on a webcam meeting or listening to Spotify, all music/audio completely stops... First I hear this noise and then the complete silence.

I have been researching about this for several days without luck. I thought that this was related to Bluetooth, but I have deactivated the Bluetooth from the startup like a month ago, and this is still happening.

I use Cinnamon as the desktop environment. I never had problems with Cinnamon previously but I am not sure if this has something to do with this issue.

Anyone could help me with this?

More information:

- My kernel: 5.4.0-66-generic
- Ubuntu system version: 18.04.2-Ubuntu
- Cinnamon runs at startup as default desktop environment (I have configured this manually, installed Cinnamon aside).
- Laptop: Lenovo Ideapad S340 / Intel Core i7 / Intel Iris Plus Graphics.

Comment: Ubuntu LTS releases have two kernel stacks available; which are you using? (GA thus 4.15 or HWE..)  If the system has crashed, there should be crash files in /var/crash/ so are there?  I see only graphics issues and no signs of crash (thus kernel is a starting point).  You mention no mouse/keyboard, so you can't switch to a text terminal & login? to explore, no SysRq commands can be used to get control of GUI, reboot etc?  How did you load Cinnamon? and from where?  Are you using Ubuntu? a remix? or something else?

Comment: Hi @guiverc, Answering your questions: * This is my kernel: 5.4.0-66-generic * System version: 18.04.2-Ubuntu * I am not able to use the keyboard or to open a terminal. Next time I will try the SysRq commands. * Cinnamon is loaded at the start (is my default environment). ----
There are crash files at /var/crash: _usr_bin_cinnamon-launcher.146916563.crash
_usr_bin_cinnamon-launcher.146916563.upload
_usr_bin_cinnamon-launcher.146916563.uploaded

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?   Your system is behind on uipgrades; as a fully upgraded *bionic* system will report itself as running 18.04.5 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/08/08/ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-released/) meaning your system hasn't received updated packages since before 2019-August-08 ? or your system is frozen behind like a Mint system does (due to the use of runtime *adjustments*), so I'd suggest either update your system, or you're off-topic here as Mint is neither Ubuntu, nor *flavor* (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of Ubuntu and you're off-topic (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Hi @guiverc, yes, I am using Ubuntu 18.04, not Mint. I have installed Cinnamon manually (this is possible running the commands described here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-cinnamon-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux). I have no idea what is going on with the updates, so I will check this. My computer was configured by my office Service Desktop, so I am not able to update certain things. I will try to upload the system to 18.04.5 version and I will tell you about it!